# issue iteration over "aws_wafv2_regex_pattern_set" terraform wafv2

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am facing issue in terraform wafv2. Currently i am stuck in while creating the aws_wafv2_regex_pattern_set resource. The aim is regular expression with loop iteration.

```
resource "aws_wafv2_regex_pattern_set" "example" {
#for_each = var.parameters 
name        = "example"
description = "Example regex pattern set"
scope       = "REGIONAL"
regular_expression {
for_each = var.parameters 
regex_string = each.value
}
#regular_expression {
#  regex_string = "/api"
#}
tags = {
Tag1 = "Value1"
Tag2 = "Value2" 
}
}
```

Secondly i check terraform documentation.

[terraform error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKzWF.png)

But i am getting this

[terraform wafv2 aws_wafv2_regex_pattern_set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSZQ6.png)

Not know how to iterate over this resource on block

Comment: Can you provide actual link to the documentation, not screenshot of its fragment?

Comment: Here the relevant  link https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/wafv2_rule_group

Comment: Must be mistake in the example. The docs for  [wafv2_regex_pattern_set](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/wafv2_regex_pattern_set) show no such field as `regular_expression_list`.

Comment: ok from this example https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/wafv2_regex_pattern_set can we iterate from this field  "regular_expression".

Comment: Basically, i don't want to wright   regular_expression {.... } for multiple time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can iterate and dynamically create `regular_expression`, using [dynamic blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html). For example:

```
variable "expression_list" {
  default = ["exp1", "exp2"]
}

resource "aws_wafv2_regex_pattern_set" "example" {
  name        = "example"
  description = "Example regex pattern set"
  scope       = "REGIONAL"

  dynamic "regular_expression" {
    for_each = var.expression_list
    content {
       regex_string = regular expression.value
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: It works. use this expression under the content field                                                   regex_string = regular_expression.value

Comment: I have this errore during terraform plan: A reference to "each.value" has been used in a context in which it unavailable, such as when the configuration no longer contains the value in its "for_each" expression. Remove this reference to each.value in your configuration to work around this error.

Comment: @Daniele Please make new question specific to your issue.

Comment: The problem was "each.value". I've changed with :
dynamic "regular_expression" {
    for_each = toset(var.regular_expressions)
    content {
      regex_string = regular_expression.value
    }
  }

And it works:
Thank you